# How can I set a label, that belongs to a model, dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

so let's say I have a registration model and I have:

`[Display(Name = "")]`
`public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }`

How can I load the `[Display(Name = "")]` dynamically so that the display name is actually the secret question.  I am getting a question from the database and I need this to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your data into a ViewBag and use the ViewBag to populate the label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use unobtrusive validation properties for dynamic data.
You will need to send the information to the view and display it manually.

This can be accomplished in many ways, depending on how you are generating your views.

A very simple way of doing it is:

Controller:

```
myViewModel.SecretQuestion = GetSecretQuestion();
```

View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SecretQuestion)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SecretQuestion)
```

Comment: I have tried doing something like that, I guess I don't understand the whole architecture of MVC yet as I do not know how to get access to my model from my controller

Comment: In your controller you need to import the namespace your model is under eg. `using MyProject.Models;`.  In your view, it is declared at the top of the page like this: `@model MyViewModel` and passed through your controller `return View(myViewModelWithData);`

Comment: but the "HttpGet" version of the controller method is kind of like the page load and all it does is return ContextDependentView();